# pagination with jQuery datatable not working

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, jquery-pagination

I am attempting to have page numbers at the bottom of my data table. Following an example I have attempted to do so with the following:

```
$('#table_id').dataTable( {
    "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "pagingType": "full_numbers"
});
```

My table's id is 'table_id' and I have included the following scripts:

```
<script src="https://datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

When I include the pagingType parameter, the table only shows 10 rows, however the numbers do not appear at the bottom of the table for the user to look at other pages. No errors are given in the console.

Comment: Works ok for me. [https://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/2440/](https://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/2440/)

Comment: Deleted my answer. You're adding jquery twice. Check your console for errors.

Comment: @ Nicolás Carlo the only message in the console is: 'Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.'

Comment: @markpsmith any idea why it wouldn't be for me?

Comment: @markpsmith There is no paging which I'm assuming is what the OP wants.

Comment: get rid of <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> and add the css files. It should work.

Comment: @Nicolás Carlo thanks for your help. I didn't realise i was missing a CSS file, apologies. I can't seem to locate the url for it, could you direct me?

Comment: I'll update my answer.

Comment: if you want more than 10 rows per page, have you tried: `"pageLength": 25`? This would go right after `"pagingType": "full_numbers"` (don't forget a comma after this). You may also need `"paging": true,`